# Backand.signup() "The following action: "Create My App User" failed to perform: Self referencing loop

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic-framework, backand, jint

I'm using ionic and backand to create an application.

When creating a new user, it does create a new one in the "Security & Auth" => "Registered Users". Apparently it's the link between my database and the internal backand users database... I inserted a console.log(err) in that action and this is the output:

> "The following action: "Create My App User" failed to perform: Self
>   referencing loop detected for property 'Engine' with type
>   'Jint.Engine'. Path 'Engine.GlobalEnvironment.Record'."

These are the pieces of relevant code:

```
.service('SignupService', function(Backand) {
  var service = this;
  service.signup = function(firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword) {
    return Backand.signup(firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword);
  }



  .controller('SignupCtrl', function (Backand, $state, $rootScope, SignupService) {
var signup = this;

function register() {
  SignupService.signup(signup.firstName, signup.lastName, signup.email, signup.password, signup.password)
    .then(function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('authorized');
      $state.go('signup2');
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}

signup.register = register;
})
```

Just one more thing, when i test the 'Create my App User' action in the backand interface, the exception is just the same.

Comment: Please add the 'Create my App User' action to your question, The problem seems to be in the server side code.

Comment: I switched to a new project and everything was fixed. Didn't have any data on it yet so I'm gonna stay on this one for now, but thanks!